# How to use variables across different files with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So I've written a tkinter program, and everything works, hurray! But the entire program is written in one big, messy file and it has made it hard to maintain because it's so organized. I want to clean up the program by creating functions and storing those functions in separate .py files that I call on when I need to use them.

My main file is a tkinter program and obviously is a continuous loop. The program accepts user input from a GUI, and executes code with variables that change depending on what the user inputs (after they press a button). Though when I try and use the variables that I obtain inside the tkinter loop, I can't use those variables inside other .py files.

To clarify EXACTLY how the code works: User types variables into GUI, User presses submit button, Variables are recorded, and code executes with those variables, all inside of a tkinter main loop.

How can I share variables from a tkinter loop across multiple .py files so that I can organize my code into separate files?

Comment: Just normally as you would do like `import filename` ? Or is there a problem with that?

Comment: It seems like when I try and use any of the variable names from the tkinter loop, the other files can't see those variables. I have it setup so that the main file imports all of the other files because they contain functions that the main file will use to clean things up. Is there another way of cleaning things up with multiple files?

Comment: Without any code it's hard to say

Answer (score 0):

When you import a python file in another file then you can use the code written in the first file.

For example:

**first.py**

```py
def print_something(something):
    print(something)
```

**second.py**

```py
import first

print_something("hello")
```

This will print "hello".

So if your loop is running in one file, you can use the variables in the file in functions written in different files.

This can happen because when you import a file, all of the code in that file gets executed, so every function in that file can be used in the file they are imported from.

This is why at the end of a file that you want to import you use

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # do something when this file is run
    # and not imported
```

TL;DR The variables are not passed around files, the functions get interpreted in the main file.

Comment: So If I don't use that code chunk


```if __name__ == "__main__":
    # do something when this file is run
    # and not imported ```

And I haven't created the variables yet before the functions are called, then the variables technically don't exist yet because the code from the imported file is being run first?

And using that code chunk would only execute that imported file when used?

Comment: The functions are not run, they are only read from the Python interpreter, to be used in the main file. The main file is the file that you run. You can't use variables before assigning them.

Comment: Yes using that chunk, the code inside the if statement will only be true when the file is run directly and not imported.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your example with something simple and it's not working correctly.

main.py:
```import file2

x = 5

print(x)

check(x)

print(x)

```

file2.py:

```if __name__ == '__main__':

    def check():

        x += 1

        return x

```

I'm getting ```NameError: name 'check' is not defined```

Comment: The function is located at `file2.check`. You call it like this: `file2.check(x)`

Comment: It's still not seeing check whether I do ```file2.check()``` or ```from file2 import check```

Comment: Because the function returns a new value and does not change the actual "x" variable in your main file. You should use `x=5;print(x);x=file2.check(x);print(x)`. That should show you the result.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to let me pass variables back and forth between functions. Though I don't end up using 
```if __name__ == '__main__'``` 
at all because if it is in the second file then the function will never be read.